# Permission denied issue while using move_uploaded_file()

Tags: php, move-uploaded-file

I am getting below error:

> PHP Warning: move_uploaded_file(*PATH_TO_FILE*): failed to open
> stream: Permission denied in *PHP_FILE*

Note: I have already executed `sudo chown -R apache *PATH_TO_FOLDER*`.
OS: Fedora 33 (Workstation Edition), PHP ver. 7.4.14.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO!   Please post the relevant code :-)    Only the error does not tell us enough to be able to help you.

Comment: whats your output of `ps aux | grep -i 'apache\|httpd' ` ?

Comment: @tinker can't paste all the lines so here are some of them:<br/> apache 1042 0.1 0.2 472148 21184 ? S Jan24 1:46 php-fpm: pool www<br/> root 44020 0.0 0.1 35504 9816 ? Ss 15:42 0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND<br/> apache 44021 0.0 0.0 46708 5452 ? S 15:42 0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND<br/> matej 45697 0.0 0.0 221564 2608 pts/0 S+ 17:09 0:00 grep --color=auto -i apache\|httpd

Comment: might be selinux see https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/apache

Comment: @tinker turns out SELinux was the problem. Solved it by executing `semanage permissive -a httpd_t`. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out SELinux was the problem. Solved it by executing `semanage permissive -a httpd_t`.